# Showing a label message without clicking

Tags: c#, label

So I want to be able to display a message on a label without clicking the label.

```
    public void servicestatus_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mavbridgeservice = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MavBridge");

        if (mavbridgeservice.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            servicestatus.Text = ("The service is running!");
        }

        else
        {
            servicestatus.Text = "The service is stopped!";
        }  
    }
```

I tied to put (null, null) in the (object sender, EventArgs e), but that gave errors, which I don't know why. My code inside there didn't have any correlation with any clicking.

Comment: From where you are trying to change the value of the label ?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better. There should be no problem.
Which error occurred?

Comment: When I click, the label changes and it works perfectly find. I just want it to change without the user having to click on the label

Comment: At what event ? on Form Load or is it a windows service ?

Comment: so dont use the click event handler, use the mouseup or mouse enter or mouse leave or mouse over or any thousands of other events that exist in the framework...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx pick one of these hundreds of events to do what you need to do then, code cant magically work, needs an event, dont like the evnt youve got, use another one!

Comment: As Habib indicated, where are you calling `servicestatus_Click_1(null, null);` from?  Alternatively, you could also call `servicestatus_Click_1(servicestatus, EventArgs.Empty);`.  It also looks like you had a `serverstatus_click` method stubbed out, so when you created the click event from the designer, it created this `_1` version.  Double check that you are calling the correct method.

Comment: servicestatus is the name of his label i guess from looking at the code, it SHOULD work fine, he just doesnt want it to be on the click event, so tried to null the inputs on the click event,

Comment: put the whole code in a simple method and call it from where ever you like it

Comment: @RhysW Thats exactly it. What my main goal will be after this is to have the status of the service automatically refresh. I got the label from the ToolBox, in VS 2010, and I guess by it is on click.

Comment: click literally means when this label is clicked do this, click event will never fire at any other time, K'Leg explains in an answer it needs to be in a method of its own and then you can call this method whenever the label needs to be shown, like when the status chanegs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obviously wish to display the status of the server.

But you don't want o change it when the user asks for an update you want it to change automatically right?

You have two options.
EDIT:  I see now that option#1 wont work, you will need the timer option below.  I removed Option #1

Option #2
If it is changed outside your Program, then you could add a timer that asks every second or two seconds depending on how fast you wish to update your users, and in that time add your code to set the label

```
    public Timer t = new Timer();
```

Then in your main form constructor, under the InitializeComponent(); line add this

```
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Tick+=new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    t.Enable=true;
```

in the timer.Tick event run your code to determine the status(what is currently in the click event of your label)

```
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var mavbridgeservice = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MavBridge");

        if (mavbridgeservice.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            servicestatus.Text = ("The service is running!");
        }

        else
        {
            servicestatus.Text = "The service is stopped!";
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I added an update, the first option wont work for you because you are not setting the status, you are just checking it, in which case I think the timer is really the way to go.

Comment: dont forget to mention not to put this inside the click event, or it will still only happen on the click, put this everywhere ELSE you write mavbridgeservice.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running
and completely scrap the click event code

Comment: ¬_¬ in either case he was still confused about where to put it and why the click wasnt working or allowed to be nulled ect, thought if those simple things caught him out its best to be direct and say scrap the click event so its not put in the wrong place by mistake and we get another question in like 30 seconds asking why it only works when he clicks etc :L

Comment: True I was simply explaining that I made a change so someone coming in later doesn't say wtf is RhysW talking about, his comments makes no sense

Comment: I keep getting the error "'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer'" on the  public Timer t = new Timer(); portion

Comment: Easy fix, when you declare the Timer  instead of Timer t = new Timer   use System.Windows.Forms.Timer t =new Timer.  What that means is you have two using statements at the top that both have a timer under them, so when you declare Timer t = new timer, it doesn't know which one you want to use, so you have to be more specific...  You might have to add it to the new timer()  part as well->  System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()

Answer (score 1):

Putting null null in the arguments of the event handler gives you an error because the code needs to know what sent this request (the object, in this case the label) and the event arguments it uses (the e) you cant null these, it needs them to function. which is why it gives errors.

also as explained this probably deosnt fire when you click because you havent linked the labels click event with this code (the click_1 shows there is a traditional click that its linked to that youre not using)